# PHP: Converting \xc3\xa4 to ä

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to correct an encoding error.

For example, a string which should read "Morgan Pålsson - världsreporter" has been encoded as "Morgan P\xc3\xa5lsson - v\xc3\xa4rldsreporter".

How do I convert "\xc3\xa5" back to "å" and "\xc3\xa4" back to "ä"?

I've tried combinations of various encode/decode functions and iconv, but no luck.

This seems like it should be straightforward. Any ideas?

Comment: Do we have a literal \ in the string or is it really an escape sequence? E.g. is the subject $subject = "abc\\xc3"; or is it $subject = "abc\xc3";?

Comment: It's $subject = "abc\xc3";

Comment: Then I don't get the problem, this one is working just fine:
$string = "hello\r\nworld\xc3\xa4";
echo $string;

You may, however, want to look at `stripcslashes`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php

Comment: With that example I get: hello
worldÃ¤

Comment: Because you're interpreting it in the wrong encoding...!?

Comment: Ah right, it works using utf8_decode(stripcslashes($str))

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Instead, consider using UTF-8 encoding (e.g. try using Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem when decoding strings coming from Salesforce via the SOAP interface. Our solution to this `"\xc3\xa4"` problem looks really weird, but it works. Note that this is a Python solution, but maybe you can apply this to PHP as well! :)

`decoded_string=encoded_string.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')`